# Standard proof that the set of sigularities is closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove that the set of singular points of an affine variety is closed. 
Suppose $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$. As every affine tangent space $T_x$ is embedded in this $\mathbb{A}^n$ we consider the tangent bundle $TX$ as a subvariety of the product $X\times\mathbb{A}^n$. After that we introduce the projection $\pi:TX\to X$, which maps each pair $(x,v)(\in X\times T_xX)$ to $x$ (it means that the fibres of $\pi$ are exactly the tangent spaces). There are the so called fibre dimension theorems which state that given a dominant morphism of irreducible varieties $f: X\to Y$ then $$\forall y\in Y\space \mathrm{dim}(f^{-1}(y))\ge \mathrm{dim}(X)-\mathrm{dim}(Y))$$ and there exists an open subset $U\subset Y$ such that for all $y\in U$ $$\mathrm{dim}(f^{-1}(y))=\mathrm{dim}(X)-\mathrm{dim}(Y).$$ 
How can I use it to prove the original statement?
Hm... A point $x\in X$ is singular if and only if $\mathrm{dim}(T_xX)>\mathrm{dim}(X)$. Yes, it is. That is a definition. Also, for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ the set $\{y\in Y:\space \mathrm{dim}(f^{-1}(y)\ge k)\}$ is closed. That is, the set of all $x\in X$ such that $\mathrm{dim}(T_xX)\ge \mathrm{dim}(X)$ is closed. But we need the strict inequality.
I am so confused, could you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how to apply the first set of statements directly, but they do imply this [semicontinuity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42796/more-upper-lower-semi-continuous-functions-in-algebraic-geometry) of the fiber dimension that you mention at the end, and that tells you that the set of $x$ such that $\dim T_xX \geq \dim X + 1$ is closed; since (finite) dimensions are integers this does what you want.

This is a cool use of these facts but I want to add that what I consider the "standard" proof uses less technology: a point is singular iff the Jacobian matrix has rank $< n - \dim X$ there, so you write down the [minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of size $n - \dim X$ and demand that they all vanish.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that $a>b$ iff $a\ge b+1$ for integers $a$ and $b$ :)

Comment: Yes, it's much easier to work over a field...